# Is there any way to create a Singleton in MVC3 without using Ioc/ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

In using HIGH AVAILABITY SESSION MODE (sessionState mode="StateServer") and all data in session must be SERIALIZABLE.
I have not idea how can I create a singleton without session..

Thank!

Comment: The normal way to created a singleton? http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your lifetime requirement for your singleton to let us know what sort of solutions are viable to you.

That being said, your application wil run in an application domain. When you define a singleton in the way described [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx), or like Oded linked, that singleton will be alive and return the same instance following the lifetime of your application domain, which again follows the lifetime of your hosting mechanism. I'm going to assume that hosting mechanism is IIS, in which case your singleton instance will be alive untill your application pool is recycled.

In short, you can use a normal singleton even if your application is a per-call (stateless) web service. All that stateless means is that your service class will be stateless and instantiated per call. Your app domain will still live longer.